# Are OpenID urls with unicode characters in them supported on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, openid, unicode

During registration to stackoverflow I created an account on https://www.myopenid.com/. I have a unicode character in my openId URL. Stackoverflow initially accepted my registration with that URL, and I could use the site for a week or two using some cookie in my browser (I guess). Now that I reinstalled my OS, the cookie is gone and I cannot login anymore. The error is "No OpenID endpoint found." and experimentation shows that the cause is the unicode URL.

So my question is, are unicode openid's supported here? And if not, how come I was able to register using my URL? Any suggestions as to how I login to my acount again are welcome too!